# Get previous month and year using a user-defined function in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to write a function which will return me the previous month and year.
Like if the input is : function_name('February', 2015) the output will be 'January', 2014.

Comment: Please post what you have done so far. To know how to properly ask a question, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 there is the date data type, which has no time attached. You can thus remove the time portion quite easily simply by converting, then performing the DateAdd.

```
SELECT DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate()));
```

This will return a date data type. To force it to be datetime again, you can simply add one more Convert:

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate())));
```

You may not need the explicit conversion to `datetime`, though.